# Implementing the Java Iterable<E> interface

Tags: java, iterable

public class C1 implements Iterable {
           private LinkedList list;
           public static class NC1 {
              ...
           }
           ...
        x  public Iterator iterator() {
              return list.iterator();
           }
        }

but eclipse whines (at the x-ed line):

```
- The return type is incompatible with Iterable<NC1>.iterator()
- implements java.lang.Iterable<NC1>.iterator
```

I don't understand where the mistake is. Can someone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to change `NC1` to `C1.NC1`. The following compiles:

```
import java.util.*;

public class C1 implements Iterable<C1.NC1> {
    private LinkedList<NC1> list;
    public static class NC1 {
    }

    public Iterator<C1.NC1> iterator() {
        return list.iterator();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could `import static yourpackage.C1.NC1`.

Answer (score 2):

this code compiles just fine:

```
public class C1 implements Iterable<NC1> {
    public static class NC1 {
    }

    private LinkedList<NC1> list;

    public Iterator<NC1> iterator() {
        return this.list.iterator();
    }
}
```

, so there must be an error in a part you omitted

EDIT:

after seeing the other answer:

yes, I have auto-imports switched on, so you need this line:

```
import com.yourpackage.C1.NC1;
```

Comment: Which version of java / eclipse?

Comment: eclipse doesn't whine anymore with aioobe's solution.